# What purpose does reassigning a variable to itself via echo serve?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I ran across some bash code during a review that reassigns a variable to itself using echo. The variable is an array. The code basically assigns the variable to itself with `` `echo $a` ``.

```
a=(one two three)
a=`echo $a`
```

What purpose does this serve?

Comment: Ten demerits for whoever wrote that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It trims the first element of the array:

```
a=( ' one ' two three )
a=$(echo $a)
echo "<$a>"
```

Output:

```
<one>
```

You can play with various combinations of quoting:

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in {1..4} ; do 
    a=( $' one \n * two ' three four )
    case $i in
        (1) a=$(echo $a)     ;;
        (2) a=$(echo "$a")   ;;
        (3) a="$(echo $a)"   ;;
        (4) a="$(echo "$a")" ;;
    esac
    echo "<$a>"
done
```

But basically, you should use

```
a[0]=...
```

if you want to assign the the first element of an array, and

```
echo "${a[0]}"
```

if you want to output its first element.

Comment: That said, you might as well just use `${a[0]}`, which is not only easier to read, but doesn't suffer from some of the problems present in this method (word splitting, globbing, etc).